# Certain Image src="" not showing on localhost.html/localhost.php file but shows in a plain .html file

Tags: php, image, css, localhost, src

I am creating my first website as a university project, Im not very advanced, anyway I have a very distinctive problem.
My client has sent me a bunch of images in jpg format from google drive.

I have an collection.php file which dynamically populates each collection got from a JSON file.

Everything works fine except the source for the images displays nothing,
If I use certain images I downloaded from the internet then it works fine,

Funny thing is all those images that dont work on collection.php,
Dont even work when I do a test file on:
localhost/test.html,

But when I go to the folder and simply double click the test.html file, the file opens in the browser with the following URL: file:///Users/******/Sites/test.html
AND the image shows perfectly fine,
Eventually I will try on the godaddy server, so if its a server issue, I hope they will work on the godaddy server
What could be the problem?
Here is my code:

HTML/PHP:

```
    //Get the collections_id from the query string and get the ranges which make up the collection from the database
    $querystring = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $splitQS = explode('=', $querystring);
    $collectionReference = $splitQS[1];

    $file = 'json/collectionSlides_' . $collectionReference . '.json';

    //Find get and loop through JSON data which has details about collection range sliders

    $collFile = file_get_contents($file);

    $collection = json_decode($collFile);

    for ($i=0; $i < count($collection->Collection); $i++) { 
        $collectionDisplay[$i] = array(
            'id' => $collection->Collection[$i]->range_id,
            'heading' => $collection->Collection[$i]->heading,
            'image1' => $collection->Collection[$i]->slide1,
            'image2' => $collection->Collection[$i]->slide2,
            'image3' => $collection->Collection[$i]->slide3,
            'image4' => $collection->Collection[$i]->slide4,
        );
    }
```

JSON:
    {

```
"Collection":[

    {
        "range_id":1,
        "heading":"Pheonix",
        "slide1":"keyholebraandknickers2.jpg",
        "slide2":"wiredbrawithknickers2.jpg",
        "slide3":"wiredbrawithknickers3.jpg",
        "slide4":"xbraandsuspenderthong1.jpg"
    },

    {   
        "range_id":2,
        "heading":"Sophia",
        "slide1":"keyholecrossoverbraletandknickers1.jpg",
        "slide2":"keyholecrossoverbraletandknickers3.jpg",
        "slide3":"keyholecroptopandbriefs1.jpg",
        "slide4":"bustierandbriefs1.jpg"
    },

    {
        "range_id":3,
        "heading":"Lily",
        "slide1":"deepvbody2.jpg",
        "slide2":"braletandlacemeupbriefs1.jpg",
        "slide3":"pleatedwiredbraandbriefs4.jpg",
        "slide4":"deepvbody3.jpg"   
    },

    {
        "range_id":4,
        "heading":"Pearl",
        "slide1":"croptopandbriefs4.jpg",
        "slide2":"croptopandbriefs2.jpg",
        "slide3":"halftrianglecupbody3.jpg",
        "slide4":"wiredbody2.jpg"
    }       

]

}





?>
```

css:

```
#collWrap{
display: grid;
padding: 0.83em;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);/*Currently set up for 2 in one 
line, 4 seems too cramped */
grid-column-gap: 0.83em;
border: 0.08em solid red;
}

.collFrac{
border: 0.08em solid blue;
padding: 0.83em;
margin: 0.83em;
}
.collFrac h3{
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
font-size: 2em;
font-weight: lighter;
border-top: 0.08em solid #ffffff;
border-bottom: 0.08em solid #ffffff;
}

.collFrac img{
width: 100%;
display: block;
height: auto;
}
```

Vardump result:

array(4) { [0]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["heading"]=> string(7) "Pheonix" ["image1"]=> string(26) "keyholebraandknickers2.jpg" ["image2"]=> string(25) "wiredbrawithknickers2.jpg" ["image3"]=> string(25) "wiredbrawithknickers3.jpg" ["image4"]=> string(26) "xbraandsuspenderthong1.jpg" } [1]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["heading"]=> string(6) "Sophia" ["image1"]=> string(38) "keyholecrossoverbraletandknickers1.jpg" ["image2"]=> string(38) "keyholecrossoverbraletandknickers3.jpg" ["image3"]=> string(28) "keyholecroptopandbriefs1.jpg" ["image4"]=> string(21) "bustierandbriefs1.jpg" } [2]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["heading"]=> string(4) "Lily" ["image1"]=> string(14) "deepvbody2.jpg" ["image2"]=> string(28) "braletandlacemeupbriefs1.jpg" ["image3"]=> string(29) "pleatedwiredbraandbriefs4.jpg" ["image4"]=> string(14) "deepvbody3.jpg" } [3]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["heading"]=> string(5) "Pearl" ["image1"]=> string(21) "croptopandbriefs4.jpg" ["image2"]=> string(21) "croptopandbriefs2.jpg" ["image3"]=> string(24) "halftrianglecupbody3.jpg" ["image4"]=> string(14) "wiredbody2.jpg" } }

Comment: What shows in the generated HTML file after you load it in the browser? Also, check the error logs or try to turn on error/debugging in php to see if you get any errors.

Comment: Thing is when I check my phppathinfo(), there seems to be no ini or config file on my mac. When I run it in the browser, there is no error, just the alt="image1" etc shows up, This is what the console error says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Where is located the images? i don't undestand your test. Probably you use a wrong path for your images in src attributes. P.s. in your test.html how you can see the code generated by php?

Comment: I cant, I just wanted to check that it was not something to do with the images, the path is correct, because I have all my php files in the root folder and images in an images folder, i can send a screenshot if its possible. Thing is certain images which I downloaded from the internet work fine, its only the the other images which were sent that dont work

Comment: Error is 403 forbidden, not 401 not found, but I will try and check it again, but for certain files it seems fine

Comment: Check where does $coll['image1'],  $coll['image2'] etc... point to. What is the exact path? Try to print it to the browser and see. When you load it from the images/ path, do you get 403 or any other error on the server? If so, either the path is incorrect or the server is not configured correctly.

Also consider going back a few steps.
Print $collectionDisplay - does each $coll have a 'image1' up too 'image4'??? if so, that means that in your foreach loop you are trying to load 4 images on each iteration.

Comment: File path seems to be correct: http://localhost/cle*enti**ingerie/website_grid/images/swimsuit1.jpg, I guess it must be the server? No idea how to sort that out, but i will have to see, i am going to check on the godaddy server, if it works there, then its fine

Comment: I am editing this question and showing the JSON code, there might be an error I am missing

Comment: I believe the error might be in the original loop, im going to check it again

Comment: try to see if array are populated, var_dump($collection);

Comment: does the folder has the necessary permissions?

Comment: Its on localhost so I would imagine so, certain images i downloaded form the internet on the same folder work fine, these images which were sent to me dont work

Comment: The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code which means that accessing the resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason. So you have to find why this image are forbidden

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Sophiaboard2.jpg:1 There is nothing wrong with the code, its picking it up, I guess its with the server .  I also got this error: GET http://localhost/clementineLingerie/website_grid/Sophiaboard1.jpg 404 (Not Found)